# VBA code to read a word doc

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there any way to create a VBA code to read a word document via audio? as if the computer was reading the whatever is on the document. (of course all text).

Comment: That's what 3rd party software like [Dragon NaturallySpeaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_NaturallySpeaking) is for. Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks Scott - I haven't tried anything yet since i didn't know if that's even possible with VBA.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this searching on google. http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2010/06/vba-how-to-convert-text-file-to-speech.html

```
Sub Speech_FromFile_Example() 

     Dim oVoice As SpVoice 
     Voice Object Dim oVoiceFile As SpFileStream 
     File Stream Object Dim sFile As String 
     File Name Set oVoice = New SpVoice 
     Set oVoiceFile = New SpFileStream


    oVoice.Speak "This is an example for reading out a file" 
    sFile = "C:\ShasurData\ForBlogger\SpeechSample.txt" 
    oVoiceFile.Open sFile 
    oVoice.SpeakStream oVoiceFile 

End Sub
```

The code requires Microsoft Speech Object Library

VBA macro for Word:

```
Dim speech as SpVoice

Sub SpeakText()

On Error Resume Next

Set speech = New SpVoice

If Len(Selection.Text) > 1 Then 'speak selection
speech.Speak Selection.Text



SVSFlagsAsync + SVSFPurgeBeforeSpeak



Else 'speak whole document
speech.Speak ActiveDocument.Range(0, ActiveDocument.Characters.Count).Text



SVSFlagsAsync + SVSFPurgeBeforeSpeak



End If

Do
DoEvents

Loop Until speech.WaitUntilDone(10)

Set speech = Nothing

End Sub

Sub StopSpeaking()

'Based on a macro by Mathew Heikkila

'used to interrupt any running speech to text

On Error Resume Next

speech.Speak vbNullString, SVSFPurgeBeforeSpeak

Set speech = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - it didn't work. I don't get any error messages nor any audio. I'll keep looking and share my findings.

Comment: the link you provided explained it and it works - thanks GlobalJim!

Comment: @GeekzInside Glad to hear! :-) Remember to mark this answer as accepted so others searching for a solution will know!

Comment: how do i mark it as answer? i didn't see the option to do so.

Comment: @GeekzInside click the little green check mark near the up and down vote arrows next to my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful if you are using Windows 10 - I had two libraries with the same name "Microsoft Speech Object Library" - make sure you select the one which points to Windows/system32/Speech/Common/sapi.dll